# ¿Cuál es el origen de "tener un aire"? ¿De dónde viene la asociación de aire a carácter, apariencia...?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Imaginemos el diálogo:

> - Me encanta esa grupo de música.
>   - ¿Por qué?
>   - Sus canciones **tienen un aire** melancólico pero a la vez humorístico.

Es decir, hablamos de *tener un aire* en el sentido de apariencia, manera de ser ya sea en el sentido físico o psicológico.

También podemos decir:

> - Ese señor **tiene un aire** triste, siempre se le ve solo.

En todas ellas se utiliza *aire*:

> [**aire**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1L3KU50)
>   *Del lat. aer, -ĕris, y este del gr. ἀήρ aḗr.*
>   4. m. Apariencia, aspecto o estilo de alguien o de algo. *Me impresionó su aire de tristeza.*

Pero en esta entrada también se recogen expresiones que inciden en vincular *aire* con *carácter*, *humor* y demás cualidades:

> *aire de suficiencia*
>   1. m. Afectación de magisterio.
>
> *coger el aire a algo*
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Acostumbrarse a su funcionamiento o aprender a realizarlo.
>
> *coger el aire a alguien*
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Acostumbrarse a su carácter.
>
> *de mal aire*
>   1. loc. adv. De mal humor.

Mirando en el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) observo que la acepción 4. indicada más arriba (*Apariencia, aspecto o estilo de alguien o de algo*) es relativamente reciente, apenas se incorporó al DRAE en 1992, pero entradas como *de mal aire* ya estaban en 1780.

Así pues mi duda es: ¿de dónde viene la asociación de *aire* a *carácter*, *apariencia*, etc?

Comment: En inglés y en francés también se usa la expresión.

Comment: Una divagación: Nótese que _aire_ y _aura_ tienen el mismo origen griego, y que _aura_ ("viento suave") evolucionó primero a "aliento" y después a "espíritu". Es como si en la respiración residiera el alma. Si cambias aire por aura en "Ese señor tiene un **aura** triste" casi ni se nota la metáfora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Online Etymology aparece esto sobre *[air](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=air)* en inglés:

> **air (n. 2)**
>   1590s, "manner, appearance" (as in *an air of mystery*); 1650s, "assumed
>   manner, affected appearance" (especially in phrase *put on airs*, 1781),
>   from French *air* "look, appearance, mien, bearing, tone" (Old French
>   *aire* "reality, essence, nature, descent, extraction" (12c.); compare
>   *debonair*), which is perhaps from Latin *ager* "place, field, productive
>   land" (see *acre*) on notion of "place of origin."
>
> But some French sources connect this Old French word with the source
>   of *air* (n.1), and it also is possible these senses in English
>   developed from or were influenced by *air* (n.1); compare sense
>   development of *atmosphere* and Latin *spiritus* "breath, breeze," also
>   "high spirit, pride," and the extended senses of *anima*.

Es decir, resumiendo y para quien pueda no entender el inglés: que *air* en el mismo sentido aproximado que este *aire* en castellano puede ser que provenga del francés antiguo, y éste tanto del latín *ager* ("lugar, campo", en el sentido de "origen, extracción" y por extensión "esencia"), como del latín *aer* "aire, atmósfera" por la misma asociación que cambió el sentido oiginal de *spiritus* y *anima* y que nos dio el sentido figurativo moderno de *atmósfera*.

La cronología coincide: la palabra inglesa aparece atestiguada con su sentido de "apariencia" en la década de 1590 y la de "afectación" en la de 1650. El francés se transformó en lengua vehicular y de prestigio en Europa a partir del siglo XVII y especialmente en el siglo XVIII, por lo cual no sería extraño que nuestro *aire* fuese un calco del francés, con el mismo significado ya adoptado por el inglés.

Answer (score 2):

Pues debe de venir de muy antiguo. Fíjate en la entrada de Covarrubias (1611) sobre la palabra "ayre":

> AYRE. [...] Tenemos muchas frases tomadas desta palabra Ayre. [...] Tener ayre, tener gracia una cosa. Darle ayre, entallarla bien y agraciadamente. Tener Pedro el ayre de Juan, es parecersele en el movimiento, o en el cuerpo y rostro. [...]

Nótese que no da una definición exacta de lo que significa la palabra (más allá de una disertación inicial acerca de que es uno de los cuatro elementos, concretamente el espacio que hay entre el elemento del fuego y el de la tierra). Pero sí da muchos ejemplos de frases hechas con esa palabra.

Si nos vamos más atrás, en el de Nebrija (1495) vemos las siguientes entradas:

> Aire en la cara del hombre. Vultus, us.
>   Aire de cara gracioso. Decor, oris.

Si buscamos estas dos palabras en latín, "vultus" significa "rostro, aspecto", mientras que "decor" significa "bello, magnífico, elegancia, lo que conviene". Es decir, el aire en la cara es el aspecto de la persona, definición que mencionas y que ya existía en 1495. De la segunda (aire gracioso) sale la expresión "salir airoso" (salir con gracia y elegancia de una situación).

Sobre la asociación en sí, puede ser complicado encontrar el origen. Covarrubias ya enlaza la palabra con el latín *aer*, "aire". En la antigüedad ya muchos consideraban el alma como algo inmaterial, al igual que el aire, hasta el punto de que los asemejaban o consideraban que la primera estaba hecha de lo segundo. Recordemos que el aire se consideraba uno de los cuatro elementos primordiales, así que para ellos no era descabellado que el alma estuviera hecha de este elemento primordial. Por otro lado, desde antiguo se ha considerado que la cara es el espejo del alma. Por lo que de ahí a considerar que alguien "tiene un aire" a otra persona si sus rostros (alma, aire) se parecen, es un paso que tiene su lógica.

Answer (score -1):

Los humanos tenemos olfato, pero no tan bueno como muchos otros animales, y dependemos de la vista y el oído para nuestra supervivencia. De hecho, es el sentido menos desarrollado de nuestra especie. (https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/07/150702112110.htm)

El olor pasa por vía aérea, por lo que "tiene un aire" podría ser sinónimo a "tiene un olor a".

En conclusión, si alguien tiene un aire a algo, se entiende que tiene similitudes con otra cosa, pero que no lo sabe con certitud, al no confiar en su sentido del olfato.